# How to avoid spaces and empty sections in the report in the state of empty data sources

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-2008

Q:

I wanna to ask about report design issue.

If my report data source is set of data tables in a data set. And in some cases the `data table` is empty, **How to hide the table(I mean the control which use this empty datatable as a data source) to prevent spaces and empty data in my report ?**. Is there some control like panel to make it invisible under the condition of( the source of specific table is empty)?

Please explanation,because I'm a beginner for the reports.and I'm confused about the design ,and formatting issues.I will be grateful if there are resources to help me in this area.

For Example:

[image]

How to hide both of the title and the table if the data table used as a data source to the table below is empty without leaving spaces between sections of my report.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Set the tablix/table visibility hidden property to = CountRows() = 0

The CountRows() for a dataset return's the number of rows the query returns.

When CountRows() returns 0 rows (no data) the condition return's TRUE 
for the hidden property of tablix, so it hides the tablix control
```

To hide the title you have two options:

1. Use a list to contain both the table and the title textbox. If CountRows equals 0 hide the list (which contains the other two)
2. Add a row on top of the table column headers. Place the title there.

Comment: And what about the title of this section . How to hide it according to the data table state.

Comment: Thanks s lot . i add an image to clarify what i need more clearly.

Comment: Updated my answer. Hope it's ok now